# namespace prefix in function body

Tags: c++, namespaces

I just went through a case where i don't need to prefix the namespace  within a function that is itself declared within the namespace

Consider this:

```
namespace fs
{
    void ftest();
    typedef int uint;
}

void fs::ftest()
{
    uint p = 2; // no prefix fs:: needed
}
```

This actually doesn't really shock me, but i'd like to have some insights : why does in actually work? Obviously this isn't koenig lookup here.

I'm using VS 2013

Comment: Because it's inside `fs::ftest()`

Comment: What surprises you? Functions in a namespace have access to everything within the same namespace (pretty much like functions in a class have access to members of the class). This is self-explanatory. Or do you want a quote from Standard?

Comment: ok, I didn't even know that, so i guess it's logical. and yeah, i'd like a quote from the standard

Comment: The process is called unqualified name lookup. Not a standards quote but you can learn how it works [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup).

Comment: thanks, upvoted because you were the first giving the name of the process

Answer (score 3):

This is basic *unqualified lookup*. The relevant rule is in [[basic.lookup.unqual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#6):

> A name used in the definition of a function following the function’s *declarator-id* that is a member of namespace `N` (where, only for the purpose of exposition, `N` could represent the global scope) shall be declared
>   before its use in the block in which it is used or in one of its enclosing blocks (6.3) or, **shall be declared before its use in namespace `N`** or, if `N` is a nested namespace, shall be declared before its use in one of `N`’s
>   enclosing namespaces. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> namespace A {
>     namespace N {
>         void f();
>     }
> }
>
> void A::N::f() {
>     i = 5;
>     // The following scopes are searched for a declaration of i:
>     // 1) outermost block scope of A::N::f, before the use of i
>     // 2) scope of namespace N
>     // 3) scope of namespace A
>     // 4) global scope, before the definition of A::N::f
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*